# C# redrawing rectangles logic

Tags: c#, logic

this may be more of a question of logic than of syntax so i dont know if anyone would be willing to help but I have a list of type Rectangle that i need to loop back and forwards through.

the list contains a random range of rectangles from left to right with random widths and heights e.g.

```
                  ___________ 
____              l         l
l  l              l         l
l  l   ________   l         l
l  l___l      l   l         l
l  l   l      l___l         l
l__l___l______l___l_________l
```

I need to rotate the rectangles so that they look like the following

> ```
>                   ___________
> ____              l         l
> l  l              l         l
> l  l   ________   l         l
> l__l___l______l   l         l
> l_____________l___l_________l
> l___________________________l
> ```

So i think the easiest way to do this is to take the first rectangle and compare it to the next one along. However when i try to get the values of the next rectangle along i get stuck because i'm going out the range of the possible indexes

This is the code to draw the original rectangles which works as it is meant to

```
Graphics RectangleGraphics = DrawingSurface;

            for (int x = 0; x < userInput; ++x)
            {
                int Height = myRectangleClass.genHeight();
                int Width = myRectangleClass.genWidth();
                RectangleGraphics.DrawRectangle(Pen, myRectangleClass.MyRectangle(startPositionX, (450 - Height), Width, Height));

                ReadWrite.writeOutput(startPositionX, (450 - Height), Width, Height);
                startPositionX = startPositionX + Width;
            }
```

I'm attempting to use the following code to rotate the rectangles while maintaining the same shape but i obviously get out of range errors

```
Graphics RectangleGraphics = DrawingSurface;

        int previousX = 0;
        int width = 0;
        int height = 0;
        int xCoordinate = 0;
        int yCoordinate = 0;


        for (int i = 0; i < Rectangles.Count; ++i)
        {
            if ((Rectangles[i].X < Rectangles[i + 1].X) && (Rectangles[i].Height > Rectangles[i + 1].Height))
            {
                width = Rectangles[i].Width;
                height = Rectangles[i].Height - Rectangles[i + 1].Height;
                xCoordinate = Rectangles[i].X;
                yCoordinate = 250 - height;

                Rectangle DrawRec = myRectangleClass.MyRectangle(xCoordinate, yCoordinate, width, height);
                RectangleGraphics.DrawRectangle(Pen, DrawRec);
            }
        }
```

I need to look at the current rectangle, if the next rectangles are heigher then i know the width needs to increase but it needs to stop when it reaches a rectangle that it lower than its current height. Once it reaches that rectangle it needs to move backwards incase its not the first rectangle in the series.

If you have any suggestions or ideas on a better way to redraw the rectangles please let me know.

Answer (score 0):

Rather than reusing the rectangles by rotating them, it's easier to treat them as input which are used to generate the correct output rectangles.

Another way to make this simpler is to cut the desired rectangles out rather than trying to build them up.

Here is a simple algorithm. First you will need a cookie-cut shape made by inverting your pattern. Here's the cookie cut shape:

```
____________________________
1  1  1       1   1_________1
1__1  1       1   1
   1  1       1   1
   1  1_______1   1
   1__1       1   1
              1___1
```

which was formed from the original:

```
                  ___________ 
____              l         l
l  l              l         l
l  l   ________   l         l
l  l___l      l   l         l
l  l   l      l___l         l
l__l___l______l___l_________l
```

Now start with a rectangle the size of your entire area

```
____________________________
1                           1
1                           1
1                           1
1                           1
1                           1
1                           1
1___________________________1
```

Take the tallest rectangle from the cutter:

```
              _____       
              1   1     
              1   1
              1   1
              1   1
              1   1
              1___1
```

Use it to divide the large rectangle like this:

```
____________________________
1             1###1         1
1             1###1         1
1     1       1###1    2    1
1             1###1         1
1             1###1         1
1_____________1###1_________1
1__________3________________1
```

Now you have 3 rectangles in your output.

Continue by taking the next largest rectangle from the cutter:

```
   ____ 
   1  1      
   1  1     
   1  1       
   1  1  
   1__1
```

Calculate which output rectangle it is in (it will only be in one) and use it to divide that rectangle:

```
____________________________
1  1##1       1###1         1
1  1##1       1###1         1
1  1##1       1###1         1
1  1##1       1###1         1
1__1##1_______1###1         1
1_____________1###1_________1
1___________________________1
```

And so on. Eventually you will generate the rotated pattern.